# Access to mail contacts directory in Android iOS app we are making

Tags: android, iphone, email

Just to preface this post: I am not a developer. I am working with a dev trying to create an android & iOS app. We would love to have a feature whereas the user were to type in an email address in a field within the app and the address would then autofill in that field as they type (the same way that gmail auto-guesses the email address as you type it out in the search field). The app would in some way have to access the email client on their phone and pull the address. Has anyone heard of anything remotely regarding this case?

Thank you very much!